# Why is it not opening VerifyNumber intent?

Tags: java, android, performance, retrofit2

Here I am trying open an intent on response from API but its skipping that VerifyNumber intent class. This response I am getting through retrofit 2.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
    try {
        String data = response.body();

        if (!data.equals("99")) {
            Log.d("appLoginTag:", data);
            try {
                Log.d("url", "" + data.toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data.toString());
                JSONObject obdata = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Data");
                String hasError = obdata.getString("hasError");

                if(hasError.equals("false")) {
                    String callBackNo = obdata.getString("callBackNo");
                    Utils.setDataToSharedPref(LoginActivity.this, Utils.CALL_BACK_NUMBER, callBackNo);
                    Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, VerifyNumber.class);
                    in.putExtra("mobile", Checkmobile);
                    in.putExtra("TokenKey", "");
                    in.putExtra("DeviceId", _deviceId);
                    in.putExtra("OTTPcode", LoginActivity.this.OTP);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = obdata.getString("errorMsg");
                    CommonMethods.ShowError(errorMsg, 1, LoginActivity.this);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(hasError.equals("false"))` what is returning?

Comment: can you add your response ?

Comment: its returns a callbackNo.

Comment: @Ace I am asking about data, what you get in data string?

Comment: @MilanPansuriya {"ContentEncoding":null,"ContentType":null,"Data":{"id":0,"userId":null,"username":null,"password":null,"userType":0,"name":null,"mobile":null,"createdDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","endUserIP":null,"active":0,"deleted":0,"callbackNo":"3159889377","hasError":false,"errorMsg":null},"JsonRequestBehavior":1,"MaxJsonLength":2147483647,"RecursionLimit":null}

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<String> call, retrofit2.Response<String> response) {
    try {
        String data = response.body();

        if (!data.equals("99")) {
            Log.d("appLoginTag:", data);
            try {
                Log.d("url", "" + data.toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data.toString());
                JSONObject obdata = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Data");
                String hasError = obdata.getBoolen("hasError");

                if(!hasError) {
                    String callBackNo = obdata.getString("callBackNo");
                    Utils.setDataToSharedPref(LoginActivity.this, Utils.CALL_BACK_NUMBER, callBackNo);
                    Intent in = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, VerifyNumber.class);
                    in.putExtra("mobile", Checkmobile);
                    in.putExtra("TokenKey", "");
                    in.putExtra("DeviceId", _deviceId);
                    in.putExtra("OTTPcode", LoginActivity.this.OTP);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = obdata.getString("errorMsg");
                    CommonMethods.ShowError(errorMsg, 1, LoginActivity.this);
                }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove this condition  if (!data.equals("99"))